# How to give hyperlink in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, html

I am writing code in my wordpress themes folder.
i am giving hyperlink to another page from my index page but its not  working.

```
     <li><a href="admin/admin.php"> Admin </a></li>
```

Link is not working like this

I am new to wordpress.
Can anybody help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use full path for that link, so, that would be http://site-url/slug.
You can achieve that by using following code.

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/admin/admin.php"> Admin </a></li>
```

The site_url template tag retrieves the site url for the current site (where the WordPress core files reside) with the appropriate protocol, 'https' if is_ssl() and 'http' otherwise.

You can read more about [site_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url)

Comment: what is the issue you are facing can you please tell me in brief, and have you checked by inspect this code, what that is prints in href ?

Comment: You have to create one page in admin slug would be admin and change your hyperlink to following code <li><a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/admin"> Admin </a></li> and add the this code to top of page <?php
/*
Template Name: admin
*/
?> and select admin as page template. now you can sure visit that link.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/admin.php">Admin</a>
```

**Another way** is to create template in wordpress theme folder

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: templatename
*/
?>
```

Comment: do i need to write this at top of my page (admin.php)

Comment: Yes add in admin.php,then you need to create page and set template from wp-admin..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the full path.

In order to get url of the home page,

use this.

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('site_url'); ?>/admin">Admin</a>
```

to get file use this.

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/admin/admin.php">Admin</a>
```

For more information about the bloginfo

See this url -> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/